# Using Sublime Text 2 for C++ and OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, sublimetext

I am a newbie to programming and learning to code with OpenGL through C++ in Sublime Text 2. I have javascript experience and I am now using Sublime Text 2 with MinGW to compile C++ code. It runs just fine with normal C++ code, but with OpenGL it returns problems. I have installed GLUT in MinGW.

For example:
I found this simple code from youtube video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SAmD_Aq1Un4

```
#include <GL/GLUT.h>
#include <iostream>

void render(void);

void keyboard(unsigned char c, int x, int y);

void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
    glutCreateWindow("Simple GLUT Application");

    glutDisplayFunc(render);    
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);

    glutMainLoop();
}

void keyboard(unsigned char c, int x, int y) {
    if (c == 27) {
        exit(0);
    }
}

void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y) {
    if (button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON) {
        exit(0);
    }
}

void render(void) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
        glVertex2f(-0.5, -0.5);
        glColor3f(0, 1, 0);
        glVertex2f(0.5, -0.5);
        glColor3f(0, 0, 1);
        glVertex2f(0.0, 0.5);
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

When I build the file it says the following:

```
C:\Users\HARIOM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc9WOgBg.o:openGL_Glut.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `__glutInitWithExit'
C:\Users\HARIOM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc9WOgBg.o:openGL_Glut.cpp:(.text+0x37): undefined reference to `__glutCreateWindowWithExit'
C:\Users\HARIOM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc9WOgBg.o:openGL_Glut.cpp:(.text+0x52): undefined reference to `__glutCreateMenuWithExit'
C:\Users\HARIOM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc9WOgBg.o:openGL_Glut.cpp:(.text+0x80): undefined reference to `glutInitDisplayMode'
C:\Users\HARIOM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc9WOgBg.o:openGL_Glut.cpp:(.text+0x94): undefined reference to `glutInitWindowPosition'
C:\Users\HARIOM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc9WOgBg.o:openGL_Glut.cpp:(.text+0xa8): undefined reference to `glutInitWindowSize'
C:\Users\HARIOM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc9WOgBg.o:openGL_Glut.cpp:(.text+0xc0): undefined reference to `glutDisplayFunc'
C:\Users\HARIOM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc9WOgBg.o:openGL_Glut.cpp:(.text+0xcc): undefined reference to `glutKeyboardFunc'
C:\Users\HARIOM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc9WOgBg.o:openGL_Glut.cpp:(.text+0xd8): undefined reference to `glutMouseFunc'
C:\Users\HARIOM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc9WOgBg.o:openGL_Glut.cpp:(.text+0xdd): undefined reference to `glutMainLoop'
C:\Users\HARIOM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc9WOgBg.o:openGL_Glut.cpp:(.text+0x130): undefined reference to `_imp__glClear'
C:\Users\HARIOM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc9WOgBg.o:openGL_Glut.cpp:(.text+0x13e): undefined reference to `_imp__glBegin'
C:\Users\HARIOM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc9WOgBg.o:openGL_Glut.cpp:(.text+0x15f): undefined reference to `_imp__glColor3f'
C:\Users\HARIOM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc9WOgBg.o:openGL_Glut.cpp:(.text+0x177): undefined reference to `_imp__glVertex2f'
C:\Users\HARIOM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc9WOgBg.o:openGL_Glut.cpp:(.text+0x198): undefined reference to `_imp__glColor3f'
C:\Users\HARIOM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc9WOgBg.o:openGL_Glut.cpp:(.text+0x1b0): undefined reference to `_imp__glVertex2f'
C:\Users\HARIOM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc9WOgBg.o:openGL_Glut.cpp:(.text+0x1d1): undefined reference to `_imp__glColor3f'
C:\Users\HARIOM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc9WOgBg.o:openGL_Glut.cpp:(.text+0x1e9): undefined reference to `_imp__glVertex2f'
C:\Users\HARIOM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc9WOgBg.o:openGL_Glut.cpp:(.text+0x1f0): undefined reference to `_imp__glEnd'
C:\Users\HARIOM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc9WOgBg.o:openGL_Glut.cpp:(.text+0x1f7): undefined reference to `glutSwapBuffers'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\HARIOM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc9WOgBg.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.ctors'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[Finished in 0.8s with exit code 1]
```

Comment: This is a FAQ. It's quickly found by Google. You must add the OpenGL and GLUT libraries to the linker flags.

Comment: thanks for your reply but which faq are you referring to and what are linker flags, could you please elaborate.Thanks

Comment: FAQ as in "Frequently Asked Question". It's not in a specific list of FAQ, it's a question asked frequently. And if you don't know what linker flags are yet, I strongly suggest you Read The Fine Manual of the GCC toolchain: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html (MinGW is a GCC toolchain for Windows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I c++, if you want to use a (static in this example) library, you have to link against it. In normal english, you have to tell your compiler where it can find the implementations of the library's functions. I don't know how to do that in your editor, but usually there is something called linker settings, where you can link all the libraries you need for your project. For more info [see this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But thats what i was asking and there is hardly any documentation for sublime text 2 with c++.

Comment: @Surfer Then I would recommend against using that editor. If you are trying to learn c++, use an editor that is well-known so people are better able to help you with your problems. My personal favorite is [Code::blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/).